# Sorting long data frame as if it were wide

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to sort a data frame that's in long format, in a manner as if it were in wide format, but I do NOT wish to change the structure of the data frame to make it wide. How can this be achieved using tidyverse/dplyr tools, such as arrange, group, forcats::fct_reorder, etc?

An example:
If the data had been in wide format, it would have looked like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C"),
              col1 = c(8, 8, 7),
              col2 = c(7, 9, 3))

  id col1 col2
1  A    8    7
2  B    8    9
3  C    7    3
```

And I would simply sort it by col1 then col2, in descending order for both columns, so it would just swap the first two rows around.

As it is, I have it in long format, like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
             type = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
             value = c(8, 7, 8, 9, 7, 3))

  id type value
1  A    1     8
2  A    2     7
3  B    1     8
4  B    2     9
5  C    1     7
6  C    2     3
```

And after the sorting, I want it to look exactly like this:

```
      id type value
1  B    1     8
2  B    2     9
3  A    1     8
4  A    2     7
5  C    1     7
6  C    2     3
```

In order words I want to sort on type 1's value first, and if there are ties, then look to type 2's value to sort those ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one possible way to do it. It's not very concise but gets the job done.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    col1 = ifelse(type == 1, value, NA),
    col1 = max(col1, na.rm = T),
    total = sum(value)
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(col1), desc(total)) %>%
  select(id:value)

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   id [3]
#   id     type value
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 B         1     8
# 2 B         2     9
# 3 A         1     8
# 4 A         2     7
# 5 C         1     7
# 6 C         2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dcast()`-`order()`-`melt()` approach.

```
library(reshape2)
m1 <- dcast(df2, ... ~ id)
m2 <- m1[, order(-m1[2, ])]
m3 <- melt(m2, id=c("type"))
rm(m1, m2)

> m3[, c(2, 1, 3)]
  variable type value
1        B    1     8
2        B    2     9
3        A    1     8
4        A    2     7
5        C    1     7
6        C    2     3
```

***Data***

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), type = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), value = c(8, 
7, 8, 9, 7, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```